# Вырезать из css файла все селекторы содержащие определенный класс

Tags: css

Имеется css файл `source.css`, в котором есть селекторы содержащие css-класс `.adapt-1`. Есть ли готовое решение, как вырезать все эти селекторы и поместить в другой файл? При этом необходимо не поломать другие селекторы, которые присутствуют в файле.

**Исходник**

```
.three-columns .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-1 .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-2 .two-columns-right .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-2 .two-columns-left .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-1 .one-column .toolbar .view-mode {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 21px;
}

.adapt-1 .toolbar {
    display: block;
}
```

**Результаты**

`source.css`:

```
.three-columns .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-2 .two-columns-right .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-2 .two-columns-left .toolbar .view-mode {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 21px;
}
```

`adapt-1.css`

```
.adapt-1 .toolbar .view-mode,
.adapt-1 .one-column .toolbar .view-mode {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 21px;
}

.adapt-1 .toolbar {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ну регулярку если и можно сделать, но она какая то совсем дикая выходит. нужен полный синтаксический анализ. Это что, постоянная задача ? Если разовая - то руками в разы проще чем программно.

Comment: Задача разовая, но таким образом надо вырезать три класса. Я руками вырезал уже `.adapt-0` и потратил на это 4 часа :( подумал вдруг есть решение, а то исходный файл довольно большой. Не обязательно регуляркой. Может быть скрипт какой нибудь (желательно на php).

Comment: Ну я имею ввиду что с нуля прогу делать слишком сложно. Может какие редакторы и среды разработки есть которые это смогут. Может какие верстальщики вопрос заметят и помогут

Comment: @danil, ничего себе, 4 часа. Сколько там селекторов с adapt-0 было интересно?

Comment: @dzhioev, я не посчитал сразу, так то не много ... штук 500 наверно, просто их вырезать надо аккуратно, чтобы другие селекторы не пропали, а работа утомительная :/

Comment: За 4 часа можно было бы скрипт накатать который бы всё это сделал.. делов то, split('}') => foreach => split('{')[0] => split(',') => foreach => indexOf('.adapt-0')  (а то и сразу filter(function(item){return item.indexOf('adapt-0') ) => аккуратно раскладываем селекторы по массивам, и join(',') их обратно уже разобранными, потом join туда то что от второго split осталось и пишем в файл.